# Google Sheet - Calculate a cost

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, cost-management

I'm trying to reproduce that [lovely website](https://whatthecost.com) that helps you calculate the cost of something you bought into my personnal google sheet so it's easier for me to use it.

I'm seeking here for help since I don't really know how to adapt the math when you change the value of year/month/day.
As you may see, it's able to calculate the cost by `year`, but when you change the value to `month` for example, I don't know how to make it adjust the results.

I've tried `=SUMIF`, `=IF`, but I can't seem to find a clear way to do it.
here is the [doc](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_naJI3BLKiP8q9mhEHL5_ntOq_kuoIIQ7OJ5Kskc2cE/edit?usp=sharing)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the **[SWITCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013690?hl=fr)** function:

You can in the cell `D6` use the following formula:

`=SWITCH(F2; I2; E1/E2; I3; E1*12/E2; I4; E1*52/E2; I5; E1*365/E2)`

The logic is:

- check the cell F2 (where you have the dropdown)
- if the value of F2 equals I2 (Year) then, just divide the cost by the number of years
- if the value of F2 equals I3 (Month), then make E1*12 and divide it by the the E2 (same as (E1/E2)/12
- if the value of F2 equals I4 (Week), then calculate E1*52/E2 (same as above but with 52 weeks)
- if the value of F2 equals I5 (Day), then calculate E1*365/E2 (same as above but with 365 days)

And so on on the other cells, just change the differences between the formulas, between day, week, month and year.

[image]

Comment: You are right,
I did it with a multiple =IF statement, but the switch function is way clearer.
Thanks!

Comment: you're welcome, glad it helped, don't forget to leave the answer accepted if you think that it solved your problem